# What is the correct way to say "several, but few" in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests

What can transform this:

*"to group items into several (but few) categories, ..."*

into:

*"to group items into {word} categories, ..."*

while still conveying the same meaning? I'd like to condense this information into one shorter word.

Comment: Even though it's two words, ***a few*** takes only 5 characters, so it's probably going to be shorter than any single-word term anyone comes up with here. I'm upvoting the question because I really don't think there is a single-word term for OP's context (where actually I think ***a handful of*** would be more appropriate in terms of nuance), so I'll be interested to see what we get.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe *a handful* is very close to maintaining the original meaning and nuance intended by _several (but few)_ since it (correctly) implies there must be more than one, but no more than two or three (or what _several_ conveys on its own).

Comment: It's not exactly common, but there are a handful of written contexts where things get divided [*into **minimal** categories*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22into+minimal+categories%22) That usage has a slightly "technical, domain-specific" flavour to me, so whether it's intended or not, I understand it as implying *into the smallest number of categories adequate for the current purpose* (i.e. - *minimal = **minimized** = made as small as possible*).

Comment: I would have upvoted the comment suggesting *a few* or *a handful of* (which are very good suggestions) but I disagree with the stated rationale for upvoting the question.

Comment: Group into 'tight' categories would suggest a few, well-organised categories and would convey a minimum.

Comment: Of course ***some***  is only four letters, but I suppose it doesn’t capture the sense of boundedness that the OP wants.

Comment: Why would you assume there was any way to say that, let alone in a single word?

Comment: @SeanPianka Several is commonly [between two and just enough to not be many](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/several), by the way. I typically think of it as three to maybe at most ten. It depends on what there are several of.

Maybe you should just say how many categories you want, explicitly? "to group items into 2-5 categories, ..." or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

**Limited** goes for 7, with some thin characters for proportionally spaced fonts. From dictionary.com:

> [confined within limits; restricted or circumscribed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/limited)

Using the phrase "*to group items into limited categories*", you can
quite naturally specify any strict upper amount as the *limit*.